# How do i make scrollable column in body scaffold widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello there i got some troubles when i add a SingleChildScrollView on Column in the body of Scaffold widget i got full white Screein Please help
photos
https://pasteboard.co/K3Diclo.png

https://pasteboard.co/K3Diclo.png

whem i wrap it to SingleChildScrollView
i got a white screen (and lose my appbar)

Comment: Provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` with a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // Your items
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: i got a  white screen after that

Comment: when u wrap SingleChildScrollView i get my app bar 
when i use without wrap my app bar is be white))))

Comment: provide your code how you have implemented and the result it helps to solve problem

Comment: maybe i send my code can you check it pls?

Comment: bcs what i do never solves my problem i make too much wrap

Comment: edit your question with the process you have folowed